# RMarkdown YAML content and styling

Tags: r, r-markdown

For an RMarkdown YAML like below:

```
---
title: Title
subtitle: Subtitle
author: Author
date: 20-Jan-2019
output: html_document
---
```

the rendered version looks like this:

[image]

The subtitle, author and date are italicised by default. How do I undo this? I am not able to do this using custom CSS classes like `.subtitle` etc. Also, is it possible to get the author and date on the same line? Is it possible to add new custom value pairs? Anyone know where is the underlying default HTML template for `html_document()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
---
title: Title
subtitle: Subtitle
author: Author
date: 20-Jan-2019
output: 
  html_document:
    template: default.html
    css: your.css
---
```

you can Custom CSS and template,[Reference here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/template-pandoc.html)
And [default HTML template](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/h/default.html)

In the **default.html** file, the following line

```
<h3 class="subtitle"><em>$subtitle$</em></h3>
```

when changed to

```
<h3 class="subtitle">$subtitle$</h3>
```

removes italic subtitle.

Comment: When passing the original `default.html` through `template:default.html`, mathjax expressions do not work and custom code highlighting fails.